# Not setting a properties in the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in all the tutorials that I have seen, the state properties are set to empty strings, arrays, ...etc so I assumed it's best practice.

So is it bad practice to set the state properties by the event handler ??

```
class Form extends Component {
  state = { };

  handleOptionChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="size"
              value="small"
              checked={this.state.size === "small"}
              onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
            />
            Small
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="size"
              value="large"
              checked={this.state.size === "large"}
              onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
            />
            Large
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

the code works just fine and updates the state every time an input is selected.

Answer (score 2):

What you have written will work fine. It's considered best practice to set initial values in state for a few reasons:

1. The component has a default value when it initializes
2. Anyone reading the code knows what to expect for `state` properties (and their types)

   ```
   class Form extends Component {
     state = {
       size: 'small'
     }
     ...
   }
   ```

This will set `this.state.size` to `'small'` by default. If you don't want a default value, it's good to set an empty value of the same type you expect that state property to have.

In other words, if you're expecting `this.state.size` to be a string but you don't want it to have a default value, `state = { size: '' }` will send the message 'this state has a `size` property, which we can expect to be a string'